# Last section interferes in the header at the end of a book

Tags: header-footer, scrbook

I'm trying to make something similar to a back cover for a book, as an example showing `example-image-a`. The problem is, since the bibliography comes just before it, it interferes in the header. How do I get that removed?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makenoidxglossaries
\setglossarystyle{tree}
\newglossary*{foo}{Foo}
\newglossaryentry{x}
{
  type=foo,
  name={Dr X},
  description={ }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\vspace*{\fill}

  \begin{center}
    \Huge TITLE
\vspace*{\fill}

\gls{x}

\vspace*{\fill}

  \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index}
\label{index}
\printnoidxglossaries

\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliographie}
\label{bib}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{foo} AUTHOR, TITLE, YYY, JOUR 

  \end{thebibliography}

% WANTED: no Bibliography header below this point
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\qquad  

\end{document}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Have you considered to use a class like `bookcover` or simulary to do what you want? An Book cover, the part you can read if the book stand in you bibliography and the last page of the book cover have different sizes than your book. Ususlaly they are made in a separate file ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is only a dirty hack, because book Cover and back cover should better be done in a seperate file (they have other page sizes, for example and other or no margins ...

Okay let us have a look on the hack:

use simply the following code before your image to start a new page and make sure that there is no header (bibliography) or footer (pagenumber) printed:

```
\clearpage % <==========================================================
% WANTED: no Bibliography header below this point
\thispagestyle{empty} % <===============================================
```

With the following complete tex code

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makenoidxglossaries
\setglossarystyle{tree}
\newglossary*{foo}{Foo}
\newglossaryentry{x}
{
  type=foo,
  name={Dr X},
  description={ }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\vspace*{\fill}

  \begin{center}
    \Huge TITLE
\vspace*{\fill}

\gls{x}

\vspace*{\fill}

  \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index}
\label{index}
\printnoidxglossaries

\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliographie}
\label{bib}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{foo} AUTHOR, TITLE, YYY, JOUR 

  \end{thebibliography}

\clearpage % <==========================================================
% WANTED: no Bibliography header below this point
\thispagestyle{empty} % <===============================================
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\qquad  

\end{document}
```

you get the following last two pages:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see the header and the footer is gone on the last page ...